# Filtro de informações de candidatos a emprego

Tags: if, else

Um programa que filtre informações de candidatos a emprego: O nº de candidatos por sexo.... Tem um erro nesse if, ta retornando só `m` ou só `f`

```
package livroex_pag69;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Ex_09_Recrutamento {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String sexo, exp, esc, continuar ;
        int idade, m = 0, f = 0, numCand = 1;


    do{
        idade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Idade: "));
        sexo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sexo [m/f]: ");           
        esc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cite a escolaridade:  ");
        exp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Possui experiência [s/n]: ");
        numCand++;
        continuar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar? [s/n]  ");

        }while(continuar.equals("s"));

        for (int i = 1; i < numCand; i++){
             if(sexo.equals("m")){          
                 m++;           
             }else{
                 f++;
             } 


        }

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Número de candidatos masculino: " + m+
                                     "\n Número de candidatos feminino: "+f);     

    }

}
```

Comment: Sua lógica está incorreta, pois o "for" só será executado quando continuar for diferente de s, logo só haverá apenas um resultado, sempre retornará apenas um sexo, reavalie seu laço de repetição do while

Comment: Ola Thiago, bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour] -- Fiz uma alteração no titulo e descrição de sua pergunta se minha alteração não representa sua necessidade você pode reverter-la acessando esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/389175/revisions) e escolhendo a revisão que melhor lhe atende. =D

Comment: Obg Icaro, como há o limite de caracteres, me perco nessa parte. valew.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está re-escrevendo as mesmas variáveis toda vez que passa pelo seu `do-while`, para resolver o seu problema, você deve armazenar os valores em um `array`, ou qualquer outro tipo de lista se preferir.

Atualmente, a sua impressão sempre está sendo a ultima recebida nos inputs.

EDIT: No caso de não poder usar `arrays` ou `listas`, como citado no comentário, você deve alterar a ordem em que acontecem os seus comandos, fazendo com que a condicional e a impressão sejam feitas dentro do loop `do-while`. Sendo assim, serão impressas após os inputs, a cada iteração do laço.

Comment: Olá, não posso usar arrays ou lists. Deve ser feito um por um.

Comment: Neste caso, você deve inserir a sua condicional de impressão, dentro do laço do-while, para que toda vez que você der input num valor, ele já imprima. Neste caso seu for seria inutilizado, pois você estaria imprimindo na hora do input.

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Obrigado Pedro. Tenho outras condicionais para por no programa. Valew.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha te ajudado! Se puder marcar a resposta como correta, eu agradeceria. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar explicar por partes o que esta acontecendo em seu código.

A cada interação desse bloco seus dados anteriormente informado se perdem, exceto o `numCand` que é um contador então ele é incrementado

```
  do {
   idade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Idade: "));
   sexo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sexo [m/f]: ");
   esc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cite a escolaridade:  ");
   exp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Possui experiência [s/n]: ");
   numCand++;
   continuar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar? [s/n]  ");
  } while (continuar.equals("s"));
```

Nesse outro bloco você esta fazendo um `for` baseado no contador que foi gerado pelo `do while`, ou seja, o `numCand`, porem a variavel `sexo` e do tipo `String` e sempre vai conter o valor da ultima interação do `do while`

```
for (int i = 1; i < numCand; i++) {
   if (sexo.equals("m")) {
       m++;
   } else {
       f++;
   }
```

> Exemplo:
>    Imagina que no `do while` voce entrou com as informaçoes `f`, `m`, `f`, `m`.
>    Sua variavel `sexo` vai ficar com o valor `m` , seu contador `numCand` vai ficar com o valor `4`.
>    Quando você chegar no bloco `for` você vai verficar **4x** que a variável `sexo` é igual a `m`.

#### Uma possível solução

Se você não tem a intenção de guardar esses dados e só quer saber quantas pessoas do sexo `m` e `f` foram informadas você pode colocar esse `if` dentro do proprio `do while`, ficando +/- assim:

```
  do {
   idade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Idade: "));
   sexo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sexo [m/f]: ");
   esc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cite a escolaridade:  ");
   exp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Possui experiência [s/n]: ");
   numCand++;
   continuar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar? [s/n]  ");

   if (sexo.equals("m")) {
       m++;
   } else {
       f++;
   }

  } while (continuar.equals("s"));
```